# Count Lines of Code from Java class

Tags: java, count

What would be the best way to count lines of code from Java classes excluding comments and blank lines.

Comment: From .java or .class files ? Because .java are standard text files.

Comment: There are no lines of code in .class files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [JavaNCSS](http://javancss.codehaus.org/). Also be aware that LoC is a worthless "metric".

I will now make a blatant [appeal to authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority) by citing Dijkstra:

> The practice is pervaded by the reassuring illusion that programs are just devices like any others, the only difference admitted being that their manufacture might require a new type of craftsmen, viz. programmers. From there it is only a small step to measuring "programmer productivity" in terms of "number of lines of code produced per month". This is a very costly measuring unit because it encourages the writing of insipid code, but today I am less interested in how foolish a unit it is from even a pure business point of view. My point today is that, if we wish to count lines of code, we should not regard them as "lines produced" but as "lines spent": the current conventional wisdom is so foolish as to book that count on the wrong side of the ledger.

— EWD, [On the cruelty of really teaching computing science](http://userweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD10xx/EWD1036.html)

**UPDATE**: If you're doing this as a practice exercise, then you should probably be using a parser and counting the actual statements.

Comment: I disagree.  LOC is a very helpful metric when used correctly.  I agree that measuring a programmers productivity via LOC is silly, for the same reasons you say so.  However, using LOC to measure code base growth is very helpful.  What if you had a team whose code base grew 50% during testing?  These sort of metrics are definately useful... IMHO.

Comment: @Hank Gay: the logical fallacy you're doing is not an "appeal to authority" but a "strawman" for nowhere did the OP state that he wanted to measure "programmer productivity".  Besides that, there are a **lot** of cases where LOC makes sense: for example when refactoring huge spaghetti mess, it is very useful to see, after the facts, how many **LESS* lines of code you have.  And anyway even if saying *"I'm working on a 5000/10000 lines codebase"* doesn't mean much, I doubt that your 5K/10KLOC app can do what the 300KLOC the programmer next door is working on can do.  Same for millionLOC, etc.

Comment: Even to measure the growth of the code base, it's (almost?) hopelessly course. What would knowing that your actual logic and your tests consume roughly equal LoC actually tell you? Branch coverage is almost certainly more useful.

Comment: @NoozNooz42

Re: Strawman -> I would posit that the *overwhelming* majority of cases where somebody is trying to get a LoC count boils down to some crude metric of "productivity", so it seems reasonable to assume the majority case.

Re: refactoring -> Reducing LoC through refactoring: while satisfying, it's still not very informative. Golfing your code will probably reduce LoC, but it won't help maintainability.

Re: amount of functionality -> If you start talking about multiple orders of magnitude difference, then you're *probably* right. There are probably better indicators, though.

Answer (score 3):

[CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) is a utility that does this.

If you're using Eclipse, there are [plugins](http://sourceforge.net/projects/metrics/) that do this.

Comment: Newest version available at: http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/example/Type12.1.html

Answer (score 2):

CodeAnalyzer is a good tool for `*.java` files.

We used the `FindBugs` which gives line of code from `.class` file. `*.java` file had 99 lines excluding comments & blank lines but `.class` gave only 59 lines.

So I think some more compacting happening in class file other than simply removing comments and blank lines

Answer (score 2):

switch to the directory of the classes,and enter the bash code:

```
find . "(" -name "*.java" ")" -print | xargs wc -l
```

it can show out the lines of all the *.java file and count the total lines of all the files.

Comment: The question says __excluding comments and blank lines__. The result of this command `find . "(" -name "*.java" ")" -print | xargs wc -l` does not exclude comments and blank lines.